# cookie not working with cron calling php script

Tags: php, zend-framework, cookies, curl, cron

I have set a curl cron call each minute which works perfectly when in my php db request there is no cookie variable involved:

```
$stmt4= $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM schedule_confs WHERE uyi=0  
AND callable=1 AND id_admin=2 ");
```

if the query involves a cookie like this:

```
 $id_user_conecte = Zend_Registry::get("iduser");   

$stmt4= $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM schedule_confs WHERE uyi=0  
AND callable=1 AND id_admin=".$id_user_conecte." ");
```

This will not work because the variable `$id_user_conecte` is not detected so there is no db request, I am using zend by the way. If I simply echo `$id_user_conecte` it works so there is no problem with my zend controller.
Is this normal, cron with curl not detecting the cookie in a document or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should set cookie in your CURL request

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://blog.yousoft.ru/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP Bot (http://blog.yousoft.ru)');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$header=substr($data,0,curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
$body=substr($data,curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
preg_match_all("/Set-Cookie: (.*?)=(.*?);/i",$header,$res);
$cookie='';
foreach ($res[1] as $key => $value) {
 $cookie.= $value.'='.$res[2][$key].'; ';
};
curl_close($ch);
```

Or

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://blog.yousoft.ru/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP Bot (http://blog.yousoft.ru)');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Reference (in russian): http://blog.yousoft.ru/2010/03/31/ispolzuem-curl-php-chast-4-rabotaem-s-cookies-2-sposoba/

Comment: mmh it's a cron curl call , it's implemented like this `*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/curl  http://www.yoursite.com/myscript.php`

Comment: `*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --cookie "iduser=somevalue" http://www.yoursite.com/myscript.php`

Study here for more advanced usage: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html